# Deploy nextjs app in docker with nginx reverse proxy on host

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-swarm, next.js

I am trying to use nginx on the host machine as the reverse proxy before my nextjs app which is deploy on a swarm mode. But it always shows 404 not found error with path like `_next/*****/page/index.js`.

When I connect to `http://machine-host-name:3000` it works well, but connect to `http://machine-hos-name/nextjs` it shows the 404 not found error.

Here is my nginx setting

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server;

   index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
   server_name _;

   location /nextjs {
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

       proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
   } 
}
```

Not sure which part is incorrect, kindly give my some advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to pass the `$uri` at the end of proxy_pass

Answer (score 0):

That method of reverse proxying is an anti-pattern.

1. Your proxy should be in a swarm service as well.
2. It should use a swarm-api-aware proxy agent that can update your proxy based on the changes swarm makes.

Two good ones are [Docker Flow Proxy](http://proxy.dockerflow.com/) and [Traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/swarm-mode/).